# Are there any way to do federated learning with real multiple machines using tensorflow-federated API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am studying about tensorflow-federated API to make federated learning with real multiple machines.
But I found the answer on this site that not support to make real multiple federated learning using multiple learning.

Are there no way to make federated learning with real multiple machines?

Even I make a network structure for federated learning with 2 clients PC and 1 server PC, Is it impossible to consist of that system using tensorflow federated API?

Or even if I apply the code, can't I make the system I want?

If you can modify the code to configure it, can you give me a tip?If not, when will there be an example to configure on a real computer?

Answer (score 3):

In case you are still looking for something: If you're not bound to TensorFlow, you could have a look at [PySyft](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft), which is using PyTorch. [Here](https://blog.openmined.org/federated-learning-of-a-rnn-on-raspberry-pis/) is a practical example of a FL system built with one server and two Raspberry Pis as clients.

Answer (score 2):

TFF is really about *expressing* the federated computations you wish to execute. In terms of physical deployments, TFF includes two distinct runtimes: one "reference executor" which simply interprets the syntactic artifact that TFF generates, serially, all in Python and without any fancy constructs or optimizations; another still under development, but demonstrated in the tutorials, which uses `asyncio` and hierarchies of executors to allow for flexible executor architectures. Both of these are really about simulation and FL research, and not about deploying to devices.

In principle, this may address your question (in particular, see `tff.framework.RemoteExecutor`). But I assume that you are asking more about deployment to "real" FL systems, e.g. data coming from sources that you don't control. This is really out of scope for TFF. From the FAQ:

> Although we designed TFF with deployment to real devices in mind, at this stage we do not currently provide any tools for this purpose. The current release is intended for experimentation uses, such as expressing novel federated algorithms, or trying out federated learning with your own datasets, using the included simulation runtime.
>
> We anticipate that over time the open source ecosystem around TFF will evolve to include runtimes targeting physical deployment platforms.